# Entity Framework 6 memory usage reaches 2GB

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, out-of-memory

I am building an application and am using Entity Framework 6. But I am running in to problems with memory usage. No matter what I try I sooner or later run into an out of memory error. So far I have tried the following:

- Using using for the the context.
- Save changes in batches and disposing of the context.
- Manually calling GC.Collect().

But none of these prevent the Entity framework of using more memory with every saveChanges I do. Eventually hitting the 2GB limit and crashing my program.

Is there any way I am unaware of to make the Entity Framework release all memory?

Edit

```
using (var sqlite = new myEntities())
{
    sqlite.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    sqlite.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

    foreach (var someItem in someList)
    {
        var newItem = new Item
        {
             ...
        };

        sqlite.tableName.Add(newItem);

        if (++countRecords%1000 == 0)
        {
            sqlite.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
    sqlite.SaveChanges();
}
```

As described above I also have tried setting the context without the using and disposing it after the SaveChanges.

```
if (++countRecords%1000 == 0)
{
    sqlite.SaveChanges();
    sqlite.Dispose();
    sqlite = new myEntities()     
}
```

Comment: Do you create new Context instance for each request to database?

Comment: To get help, you'll need to figure out a way to create a minimal but complete program that reproduces the memory problem. Otherwise, as you can surely understand, anything we suggest will be pure speculation.

Comment: can you share your EF query ?

Comment: Added a code sample

Comment: How many items are in `someList`?

Comment: up to a few thousand. But over time this piece of code runs several times. I know that EF is not good for bulk insert. My problem is that if a app runs for an extended period you still can get a lot if inserts and run out of memory.

Comment: Are you sure EF is eating up all the memory?  The fact that you even tried disposing and recreating a new EF context inside your loop hints to the problem being elsewhere.  The code you posted is helpful, but it still isn't an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because we can't use it to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I looked at where the memory goes and I am sure it is EF. And I did try disposing and creating a new EF context inside the loop. Ill work on an MCVE, sorry about that.

Comment: Use a memory profiler to understand where memory is used.

Answer (score 1):

If it is indeed a batch issue, try something like this:

```
int batchSize = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < = someList.Count / batchSize; i++)
{
    var batch = someList.Skip(batchSize * i).Take(batchSize);

    using (var sqllite = new nyEntities())
    {
        foreach(var item in batch)
        {
            var newItem = new Item() {...};

            sqllite.tableName.Add(newItem);
        }

        sqllite.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This inverts the using statement to dispose the sqllite after each batch, thus clearing it out and starting fresh for each batch.

This code was made in notepad++ so be careful to clean it up if you try it out.

Comment: Batch issue or not I really like this flow, thank you.